# Xamarin Android textview within bounds

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, listviewitem

I'm trying to create a listview item that consists of a textview and a button horizontally.
I want the textview to be on the left and the button to be on the right.
The button always has the same size so I want to let the textview take up the rest of the space.

My problem is that the textview (if it contains a text wider then the screen) pushes the button out of the screen.

I want the textview to not push the button out of the screen - I want the button to always stick to the right side of the screen regardless of how long the text in the textview is. 
If the text is too long to be displayed, I just want to display as much as possible (like *overflow:hidden* in HTML) without pushing the button out to the right.

Is it possible to configure my view to handle this or do I need to do al sorts of measuring of screen width and text length etc. etc.?

Here is my listview item xaml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="0">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_text"
        android:text="(123456) Item Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</TableRow>
```

I'm pretty new to Xamarin so if anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

/Aidal

Comment: Why are you using TableLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why people think using a TableLayout and nest a TableRow inside of it is a good practice for ListView/RecyclerView items...

Why are you not using a RelativeLayout which tells the button to be on the right and make the text view fill the rest of the space?

Should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Go"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_left"
        android:layout_width="match_match"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_go"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. and I think the answer to your question lays in the last line of my post.

Comment: Just like in HTML, Markdown etc, Tables should be used for content and not positioning layouts.

Comment: Although this visually works, there is still something that I need to do to make it work as intended. This is supposed to be a layout for a ListView item, so I assume that I need to do something in order to be able to catch a click outside the button and on the button, because right now I cannot catch either of the events by just using the ListView.ItemClick. I assume I need to do some override in the ListViewAdapter?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the `ViewHolder` pattern. Be careful with not attaching too many event handlers to the button click. Also for which events fires first on a click take a look at: `android:descendantFocusability`